# how to get all matching items in a list in the workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

How to get all matching items in a list in the workflow. I want to write a condition like the below,

```
if created date is today, return all items from the list.
```

How will I get all the items with created date as today to be returned in to SharePoint designer/Workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of sharepoint are you working on?

If its sharepoint 2010, I am sorry, there is no easy way. You might need to write custom action in visul studio and have it in SPD2010

If its 2013, then you can use "Call this HTTP web service" action inside SPD desinger. This method uses REST and you can get the filtered data directly.

Please refer below mentioned links for details

[How to use Call HTTP web service 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx)

[How to use Call HTTP web service 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/05/how-to-work-with-web-service-using-call-http-web-service-action.aspx)

Please make sure, you have SPD 2013 framework installed (If its on-premise)